# Read data from Firebase using Dart. Retrieve child values

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, dart, flutter

This is how i have arranged my data in firebase

[image]

I want to read this data from real-time database of Firebase, for example the child 'Name' value and make it visible in my app. The whole idea is that this information is stored from a registration form that I have applied in my app and where the user enter his information like Name, Surname. Now I want to get the value of these children.

Comment: Did you try something already ? Provide us some code you tried so we can help you

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following:

```
db=FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference().child("bKRmpPGoPjOaKHk6o8IVZYoBZbS2").child("User");
db.once().then((DataSnapshot snapshot){
 Map<dynamic, dynamic> values=snapshot.value;
      print(values["Name"]);
});
```

First, you need to add the reference at the child which is in this case the node `User`, then you retrieve the data of `Name`.

It is better if you change the database to the following:

```
 Users
   randomId
      Name: Alan
      Account: 2000
      Surname: Smith
```

That way if you want a list of users, then you just need the `Users` node and you will be able to loop and get all the names.

Comment: I will try this but I want to get the value as a variable so I can use in other parts of the code?

Comment: In my case I want to retrieve 'Name' value, to use it in another page of the app for a welcome text like 'Welcome $Name.value' (Alan in this case), but to do this I suppose that the method that you published create a kind of variable or something where the value will be stored, so i can call it in the other page. I dont know if I'm clear or not. :/

Comment: https://dartpad.dartlang.org/49e407595d08cdbecfaf2caef3d47a96 ... Take a look , thats what I want exactly to do.

Comment: you need to use this https://gist.github.com/PeterHdd/49e407595d08cdbecfaf2caef3d47a96 to edit the page, but anyway if you mean sending data to another screen then check this page: https://flutter.io/cookbook/navigation/passing-data/

Comment: Passing data from one screen to another is not the case. When the app is started, it is shown a register form when user enter his name, surname and these are stored in firebase. Creating a variable name inside your method make it impossible to use it outside i guess?...Your method and the welcomeText method are in the same class.